# How Can I find diffuse image of a material?

Tags: node-editor, image, shader-nodes

-there are nodegroups in nodegroups
-Images arent named correctly

And we need to create a function that finds diffuse image of that material and set active node

Here is what we did so far:

[Link To Code Here:](https://github.com/gafil14724/find_diffuse_image_blender_python/blob/main/activate_dif_node.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to search for nodes that are upstream of a *diffuse socket*, meaning either a socket named "Base Color" or the socket named "Color" on the Diffuse BSDF node.

This will find Image Texture nodes, then check if there is a diffuse socket anywhere downstream from the node. It also descends into node groups to look for diffuse sockets.

```
import bpy

# Yield all diffuse texture nodes.
def diffuse_nodes(node_tree):
    for node in node_tree.nodes:
        if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
            if is_diffuse_node(node):
                yield node


# Check if there is a link to a diffuse socket
# anywhere downstream from node.
def is_diffuse_node(node):
    nodes = [node]
    while nodes:
        node = nodes.pop()
        if is_connected_to_diffuse_socket(node):
            return True
        # Search downstream nodes
        nodes += [
            link.to_node
            for output in node.outputs
            for link in output.links
        ]
        # Also search inside group nodes
        if node.type == 'GROUP' and node.node_tree:
            nodes += [
                grp_node
                for grp_node in node.node_tree.nodes
                if grp_node.type == 'GROUP_INPUT'
            ]

    return False


# Check if any output of node is connected to a diffuse socket.
def is_connected_to_diffuse_socket(node):
    for output in node.outputs:
        for link in output.links:
            if link.to_socket.name == "Base Color":
                return True
            if link.to_node.type == 'BSDF_DIFFUSE' and link.to_socket.name == "Color":
                return True
    return False


# Example Usage
mat = bpy.data.materials["Material_MR"]
for node in diffuse_nodes(mat.node_tree):
    node.select = True
    mat.node_tree.nodes.active = node
    print(node)
```

Comment: Thank you that is all I needed 
thank you so much :)